# Problem when implementing a wrap class for an array when trying to implement IEnumerable

Tags: c#, arrays, ienumerable

I am implementing a class that basicaly wraps an array:

```
public abstract class IndividualBase : IEnumerable<Gene>
{
    private readonly Gene[] genoma;

    ...

    public IEnumerator<Gene> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return genoma.GetEnumerator();
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return genoma.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

The problem is that it's giving me trouble with the first `GetEnumerator()` -- it tells me that

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.IEnumerator' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator'.
>   An explicit conversion exists (are you
>   missing a cast?)

Although I understand what the problem is, I have absolutely no idea how to fix it. Anyone?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

You could try:

```
IEnumerable<Gene> typed = genoma;
return typed.GetEnumerator();
```

Just to make the compiler happy. While arrays implement the generic Enumerable interface, this isn't present on the public GetEnumerator(). With the above we simply cast to the preferred API. This is a trivial cast; no check should happen at runtime (since the compiler and CLI know it is valid).

Comment: FYI: I like this better than my `genoma.Cast<Gene>().GetEnumerator()` answer.  Cast _might_ be smart enough to do this under the hood, but it also might add an extra layer of indirection to cast each item, instead of the entire thing.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are returning an `IEnumerable`, not an `IEnumerble<Gene>`

Change it to this:

```
return genoma.Cast<Gene>().GetEnumerator();
```

**EDIT**

Keeping this around for another way to do it, BUT, I prefer Marc's answer better.